# UDDI example in SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

What is a good UDDI example?

From what I understand http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL is a WSDL, but what is its UDDI?

Comment: This link my help you to understand a bit more https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-wsdl/

Answer (score 1):

From the **docs**:

> The Universal Description, Discovery, and Integration (UDDI)
>   specification defines a way to publish and discover information about
>   Web services. UDDI has two functions: (1) it is a SOAP-based protocol
>   that defines how UDDI clients communicate with registries, and (2) it
>   is a particular set of globally replicated registries.
>
> Registering a service involves four core data structure types:
>
> - The *businessEntity* data type contains information about the business
>     that has a published service.
> - The *businessService* data type is a description of a Web service.
> - The bindingTemplate data type contains technical information for determining the entry point and construction specifications for
>     invoking a Web service.
> - The tModel data type provides a reference system to assist in the discovery of Web services and acts as a technical specification for a
>     Web service.

[image]

[UDDI page on the OASIS website](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=uddi-spec#overview)

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example?

Comment: please check these. there are many sample .[codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5844/Publish-Discover-and-Invoke-Web-Services-using-SOA)  , [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32476/Integrating-WCF-Services-into-UDDI-based-enterpris)